# How to switch earcons between the right and left speaker using Android TTS?

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech

The Android TTS allows you to set which speaker the speech comes out of by using

```
       map.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_PAN, "-1");
```

or

```
       map.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_PAN, "+1");
```

and then

```
       tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, map);
```

However you cannot do this for earcons as the parameter KEY_PARAM_PAN is not supported.
Is there anyway of switching sounds as well?

(It can be done using MediaPlayer as in this question [Get media player to play first on right speaker and then on left speaker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22367649/get-media-player-to-play-first-on-right-speaker-and-then-on-left-speaker) but that incurs significant overhead in terms of time so I cannot use it.)